# Rspec: Show a model's errors when it's not valid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I generally write something like this in my Rspec tests:

```
user.new(...)
user.should be_valid
```

The problem is, when that test fails, I don't get to see the errors on the user object. Is there a nice way to re-write this test so that in the Rspec output I'll see something like `user.errors.inspect`? I've tried `user.errors.should be_empty`, but that still just says "expected true, got false."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this by defining a custom matcher. Something like this should do the trick.

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :be_valid do
  match do |actual|
    actual.valid?
  end

  failure_message_for_should do |actual|
    "expected that #{actual} would be valid (errors: #{actual.errors.full_messages.inspect})"
  end

  failure_message_for_should_not do |actual|
    "expected that #{actual} would not be valid"
  end

  description do
    "be valid"
  end
end
```

Comment: @hammar: you can name this `be_valid` and it should work just fine.