# Sending rails errors to rspec output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, rspec, integration-testing, capybara

I am using Capybara in combination with rspec for integration testing of rails apps.

I would like any errors (routing errors, errors in a controller, anything) generated during a test to be printed the same as "puts" statements in rspec's output. Is this possible?  Additionally, is this a reasonable idea, or am I just being silly?

Comment: There is s [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6864350/rspec-show-a-models-errors-when-its-not-valid) here on SO. The solution is to define a custom matcher.

Comment: Similar, but I would like any errors (routing errors, errors in a controller, anything) generated during a test to be printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following to my spec_helper.rb file worked:

```
ActionController::Base.class_eval do
  def rescue_action(exception)
    raise exception
  end
end
```